# Почему кнопка срабатывает со второго раза и как это исправить?

Tags: android, kotlin, button

Это реализация кнопки. Но не могу понять почему срабатывает только с второго нажатия. Зачем нужна кнопка: есть recycleview с checkbox, по нажатию кнопки я открываю файл и отмечаю чекбоксы, но когда я открываю другой файл, чекбоксы уже отмечены. Снятие галочек с чекбоксов происходит только при повторном нажатие на кнопку. Как можно это исправить? Пытался: 1) продублировал действия кнопки в ней же 2) поставил кнопку в кнопку, реализация второй кнопки была идентична.

```
            productsView = recycle_color
            productsView.adapter = adapter

            val products = getProductsList()
            adapter.submitList(products)
            position = 0
            CommonData.listPosition=-1
            var itemcount:Int = 0
            if (recycle_color.adapter!=null) {
                itemcount = recycle_color.adapter?.itemCount!!
            }

            recycle_color.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,itemcount)
            recycle_color.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(position)
```

```
object CommonData {
    var listPosition = 0

}
```

Это код адаптера (скорее всего ошибка в нём, а не в кнопке)

```
private val selectedItems = SparseBooleanArray()

class ProductsAdapter(
    var c: Context,
    var model: Array<Product>,
    val itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener
) : ListAdapter<Product, ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder>(
    DIFF_CALLBACK
) {

    var product = ArrayList<Product>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        return ProductViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //holder.guideLinearLayout.removeAllViews()

        val view = holder.itemView
        view.isSelected = (position==CommonData.listPosition)
        val model = getItem(position)
        //setHasStableIds(true)
        holder.mCard.setSelected(model.isSelected)
        holder.mCheckBox.checkBox.isChecked = model.isSelected

        //holder.mCard.find

        holder.setItemClickListener(object : ProductViewHolder.ItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(v: View, pos: Int) {
                val myCheckBox = v as CheckBox
                val current = model
                if (myCheckBox.isChecked) {
                    current.isSelected = true
                    product.add(current)
                } else if (!myCheckBox.isChecked) {
                    current.isSelected = false
                    product.remove(current)
                }
                itemClickListener.onItemClicked(position)
            }
        })
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    }

    class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        private val productItemView: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        private val numberView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView16)
        private val codeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5)
        private val countView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4)

        val mCheckBox: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)
        val mConstraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constr_item)
        val mCard: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardColor)

        lateinit var myItemClickListener: ItemClickListener

        fun bind(item: Product) {

            val context = productItemView.context
            numberView.text = item.number.toString()
            codeView.text = item.code
            countView.text = item.count.toString()
            mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this)
            productItemView.setBackgroundColor(item.color)

            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun setItemClickListener(ic: ItemClickListener) {
            this.myItemClickListener = ic
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            this.myItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, layoutPosition)
        }

        interface ItemClickListener {
            fun onItemClick(v: View, pos: Int)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
                return oldItem.number == newItem.number
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `по нажатию кнопки я открываю файл` - какой файл? И каким образом `я открываю другой файл`?

Comment: @DrMcSheen, данные считываются из файла и представляются в recycle_color. Файл открывается путём нажатия на item другого recycleview. Используются файлы .csv

Answer (score 0):

Надо было всего-лишь поправить callback

```
companion object {
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
                return newItem.isSelected == oldItem.isSelected
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
                return newItem == oldItem
            }
        }
    }
```